# How to escape only unescaped quotation marks Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, escaping

I'm receiving a JSON response and I need to escape quotation marks.
This is The string I get:

```
"sign":0,"text":"Continue onto William Elton \"Brownie\" Brown Freeway, I 580"
```

Now, I need to get the string looking like this:

```
\"sign\":0,\"text\":\"Continue onto William Elton \"Brownie\" Brown Freeway, I 580\"
```

But, when I call this method

```
sectionString = [sectionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

What I get is:

```
\"sign\":0,\"text\":\"Continue onto William Elton **\\"Brownie\\"** Brown Freeway, I 580\"
```

So the problem is with the bold part, Brownie, that already had quotation marks, before I started replacing them. How can I solve this, and only escape " and not \" as well?

Comment: Why do you need to escape anything? Update your question with some relevant code. Most likely everything you are seeing is a byproduct of logging data and none of what you are trying to do needs to be done.

Comment: I posted everything relevant. I have a string that is partly escaped, and I need to escape it completely. But when I do, I mess up already escaped part. So how to go around already escaped double quotes and escape ones not escaped yet, that is my question?

Comment: Is RegExp an option? `[^\\]["']` will only grab " and ' that are not preceded by \

Comment: @Hazerd Yes, exactly what I need. Can you write me an example, please?

Comment: SteBra - @rmaddy's point I suspect is that all those quotes in your original string are **not** the same. The unescaped ones are part of the JSON structure, the escaped ones are part of a string value. If you succeed in doing what you wish you lost that distinction and can no longer parser the JSON properly. You should answer rmaddy's question, what is your higher-level goal in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you asked for, first un-escape the escaped quotes:

Use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString to change all the \"  into "

```
sectionString = [sectionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
```

Then use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString to change all the " into \"

```
sectionString = [sectionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```